# Datatables rowId starting with a number issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

According to the Datatables specs, I can add a unique ID to every row in my table:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    ajax: '/api/staff',
    rowId: 'staffId'
} );
```

However, the same spec says that IDs cannot start with a number. `staffId`in my case is a number, I tried to add some prefix to it:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    ajax: '/api/staff',
    rowId: 'id_' + 'staffId'
} );
```

However, this didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: _staffId in my case is a number._ Nope, `'staffId'` is a **string** in your code.

Comment: @hindmost, nonetheless, the source code looks like: <tr id="2" role="row" class="odd"> ... </tr> which is no good I think.

Comment: Yes! `ID` attribute should not start with Numbers as per the docs.. You need to define _Not working!_

Comment: @RayonDabre, so that was the question. How do I add some prefix when assign IDs to get something like <tr id="staff_1">

Comment: @Deka87, What is the current id after the code you have applied ? It looks good to me...

Comment: @RayonDabre it's <tr id="id_staffId"> ... </tr> for all of the rows.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `function-expression` as a value for `rowId` and return manipulated string to be used as `ID`

```js
var appListTable = $(".app-list__table").DataTable({
  dom: "",
  // Load json with list of applicants
  ajax: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/391gc",
  columns: [{
    "data": "uid"
  }, {
    "data": "location"
  }, {
    "data": "date"
  }],
  // Set rows IDs
  rowId: function(a) {
    return 'id_' + a.uid;
  },
});
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/44f0pcx2/3/)

Comment: Though so too, however it gives an error "staffId is not defined".

Comment: Have you defined it anywhere ? How do you expect it to be `staff_1` without defining `staffId` ?

Comment: stuffId comes from a JSON file. rowId: "staffId" (with quotes) works alright. Please see the official docs: https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId. The problem is that I cannot add a prefix to the ID assigned.

Comment: From the docs, the only source to set the id is `data-source`..There is no option to set it custom

Comment: Rayon, don't waste your time on this, I got the answer! =) I will post it here in a second.

Comment: Oh, you just did the same! =)) Thank you!

Comment: @Deka87, I guess I have reached there as well!

Comment: Datatables is such a powerful tool, it's really hard to cope with it.

Comment: This is the first time I put my hands in this tool! May be my prior experience made me think this way! I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple solution, just use

```
rowId: [1]
```

This will set the value of first column as row id